# Get today's day from Date.now()

Tags: javascript, date

After getting the value from Date.now() I have tried extracting the date like that:

```
Date.now().getDate()
```

However, the `getDate()` function doesn't work on it. My whole application is based on dates that are retrieved from `Date.now()` and I need to get current day of the month from the `Date.now()` value. I have done some research and I can not find a solution to it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date

Comment: Try this `new Date(Date.now()).getDate()`

Comment: cant you use `momentJs`?

Comment: `Date.now()` returns a numeric timestamp value. What you want is `new Date()` which gives you a date instance representing the point in time at which the function was called. You can use that to call `.getDate()`.

Comment: @Pointy I know this would solve the problem, but then I'd have to rewrite a bunch of code... I want to retrieve today's day from the numerical value which I got with `Date.now()`

Comment: @Vid that does not make any sense.  The timestamp value from `Date.now()` is a count of the number of milliseconds since midnight 1 Jan 1970.

Comment: @Pointy !! Thank you, I understand what you wanted to say, I got it working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.now()` doesn't returns a `Date` instance:

> The [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since
>   January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC

Being a number, it doesn't have `.getDate()` method. But, you can make use of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) without arguments to get a Date instance which has a `.getDate()` method:

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript
>   Date object for the current date and time according to system
>   settings.

So this should work:

```
new Date().getDate(); // 3
```